# Ionic 2 showing white page after hg pull

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Ive pulled a repo of a Ionic 2 project from a friend of my but when I do `ionic Serve` it is showing a white page without any errors.

I saw in my folder structure that I don't have a www/build directory and I don't know how to say  that the ionic CLI has to rebuild my project.

does anyone know the command for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I did not updated my npm. After I installed all the packages with `npm install` it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using [Ionic Lab](http://lab.ionic.io) to build your app?